# IntelliJ not showing callstack when running while Eclipse is showing the error for the same project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, logging

I am running the same test from the same project with TestNG in both IntelliJ and Eclipse. After the test is failing, IntelliJ is showing less logs than Eclipse, it is not even showing where the crash occured. The code is literally the same. Is there anything that i should setup in order to see the same log from IntelliJ as well? (to make it display the NullPointerException that i see in Eclipse, shown below):

IntelliJ log:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.





counter===0




Test ignored.
counter===1




Test ignored.
counter===2




Test ignored.
counter===3




Test ignored.
counter===4




Test ignored.
counter===5




Test ignored.
counter===6




Test ignored.
counter===7




Test ignored.
counter===8




Test ignored.
counter===9




Test ignored.
counter===10




Test ignored.
counter===11




Test ignored.



===============================================
YsRmCompetitorWorkflowSuite
Total tests run: 12, Failures: 12, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by com.rp.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListenerExt@704a52ec: 144 ms

Process finished with exit code 0
```

While Eclipse is showing the following:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
counter===0
counter===1
counter===2
counter===3
counter===4
counter===5
counter===6
counter===7
counter===8
counter===9
counter===10
SKIPPED: cw_DBtest
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.getLastRowNum()" because "testDataSheet" is null
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:161)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:429)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.getLastRowNum()" because "testDataSheet" is null
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.getStartRow(ExcelService.java:202)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.getTestDataBySheet(ExcelService.java:151)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.readTestDataFromExcel(ExcelService.java:59)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.webdriver.WebDriverBase.poModuleDataProvider(WebDriverBase.java:526)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:153)
    ... 20 more

SKIPPED: cw_UserWithoutPermission
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.getLastRowNum()" because "testDataSheet" is null
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:161)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:429)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.getLastRowNum()" because "testDataSheet" is null
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.getStartRow(ExcelService.java:202)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.getTestDataBySheet(ExcelService.java:151)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.readTestDataFromExcel(ExcelService.java:59)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.webdriver.WebDriverBase.poModuleDataProvider(WebDriverBase.java:526)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:153)
    ... 20 more

SKIPPED: cw_UserWithPermission
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.getLastRowNum()" because "testDataSheet" is null
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:161)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:429)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.getLastRowNum()" because "testDataSheet" is null
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.getStartRow(ExcelService.java:202)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.getTestDataBySheet(ExcelService.java:151)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.readTestDataFromExcel(ExcelService.java:59)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.webdriver.WebDriverBase.poModuleDataProvider(WebDriverBase.java:526)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:153)
    ... 20 more

SKIPPED: cw_CompetitorWorkflowAvailable
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.getLastRowNum()" because "testDataSheet" is null
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:161)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:429)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.getLastRowNum()" because "testDataSheet" is null
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.getStartRow(ExcelService.java:202)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.getTestDataBySheet(ExcelService.java:151)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.readTestDataFromExcel(ExcelService.java:59)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.webdriver.WebDriverBase.poModuleDataProvider(WebDriverBase.java:526)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:153)
    ... 20 more

SKIPPED: cw_DisplayEnabledWithRadius
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.getLastRowNum()" because "testDataSheet" is null
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:161)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:429)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.getLastRowNum()" because "testDataSheet" is null
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.getStartRow(ExcelService.java:202)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.getTestDataBySheet(ExcelService.java:151)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.readTestDataFromExcel(ExcelService.java:59)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.webdriver.WebDriverBase.poModuleDataProvider(WebDriverBase.java:526)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:153)
    ... 20 more

SKIPPED: cw_GetCompetitorsWithinRadius
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.getLastRowNum()" because "testDataSheet" is null
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:161)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:429)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.getLastRowNum()" because "testDataSheet" is null
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.getStartRow(ExcelService.java:202)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.getTestDataBySheet(ExcelService.java:151)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.readTestDataFromExcel(ExcelService.java:59)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.webdriver.WebDriverBase.poModuleDataProvider(WebDriverBase.java:526)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:153)
    ... 20 more

SKIPPED: cw_DefaultRadiusWithCompetitorsGridVisible
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.getLastRowNum()" because "testDataSheet" is null
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:161)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:429)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.getLastRowNum()" because "testDataSheet" is null
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.getStartRow(ExcelService.java:202)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.getTestDataBySheet(ExcelService.java:151)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.util.ExcelService.readTestDataFromExcel(ExcelService.java:59)
    at com.rp.automation.framework.webdriver.WebDriverBase.poModuleDataProvider(WebDriverBase.java:526)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:153)
    ... 20 more


===============================================
   
    Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Skips: 11
===============================================


===============================================

Total tests run: 11, Failures: 11, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@217ed35e: 183 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@6ed3ccb2: 25 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@662ac478: 95 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@3b0090a4: 16 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@3857f613: 25 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by com.rp.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListenerExt@702657cc: 168 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 24 ms
```

Comment: Please share the sample of the test where you see the issue. Also please name the version of TestNG. Thank you

Comment: Test is working now, the question was why intellij is only showing part of the logs that i can see in eclipse. It doesn't really matter what the code of the test is, since the same code is used by 2 IDEs and i get different logging.

Comment: Probably the exceptions are folded in the stacktrace? Sorry, can't name the reason without the sample where the case is reproduced. You may share the test sample privately in the issue created at YouTrack https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue